# Magento 2 : Assign related products to sku

Tags: magento2, product, related-products

I am using below script to assign related sku to main sku.
Script works well but the only **issue is it removes old sku & assign new set of sku**.

I want to know if their is any way we can just assign new sku & keep existing one's ?

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $productObject = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

        $product = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', 'Test Test');

        $linkDataAll = [];
        $skuLinks = "0012365,test1233,789456";
        $skuLinks = explode(",",$skuLinks);

        foreach($skuLinks as $skuLink) {
            //check first that the product exist
            $linkedProduct = $productObject->loadByAttribute("sku",$skuLink);
            if($linkedProduct) {
                /** @var  \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface $productLinks */
                $productLinks = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');
                $linkData = $productLinks //Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface
                    ->setSku($product->getSku())
                    ->setLinkedProductSku($skuLink)
                    ->setLinkType("related");
                $linkDataAll[] = $linkData;
            }

        }
        if($linkDataAll) {
            print(count($linkDataAll)); //gives 3
            $product->setProductLinks($linkDataAll);
        }
        $product->save();
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Get old SKU first save it in variable and then get a new one and then merge them and set it to setLinkedProductSku using $skuLink

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NileshDubey, but it will still have to save multiple sku (old + new)

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your script , you have to get product's related products and store into one variable. Then you have to merge array and find unique from both the array.

Please check your updated script.

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$productObject = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$product = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', 'Test Test');

$linkDataAll = [];
$skuLinks = "0012365,test1233,789456";
$skuLinks = explode(",",$skuLinks);

foreach($skuLinks as $skuLink) {
    //check first that the product exist
    $linkedProduct = $productObject->loadByAttribute("sku",$skuLink);
    if($linkedProduct) {
        /** @var  \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface $productLinks */
        $productLinks = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');
        $linkData = $productLinks //Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface
            ->setSku($product->getSku())
            ->setLinkedProductSku($skuLink)
            ->setLinkType("related");
        $linkDataAll[] = $linkData;
    }

}

$existingRelatedProducts = $product->getProductLinks();

if($existingRelatedProducts) {
   $linkDataAll = array_unique(array_merge($linkDataAll,$existingRelatedProducts));
}

if($linkDataAll) {
    print(count($linkDataAll)); //gives 3
    $product->setProductLinks($linkDataAll);
}
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer @Zealous Web
Could you please share your thoughts on this ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337863/magento-2-skip-error-thrown

Comment: Sure. If my answer is useful then can you please upvote?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the "old" array:

```
$oldData = $product->getProductLinks();
```

and merge it with the new array, before saving the product:

```
if($linkDataAll) {
   print(count($linkDataAll)); //gives 3
   $linkDataAll = array_merge($linkDataAll,$oldData);
   print(count($linkDataAll)); //should give all
   $product->setProductLinks($linkDataAll);
}
```