# Magento 2 : skip error thrown

Tags: magento2

Is their any way we can skip through this ?

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('Any error Msg.'),
                                $e
                            );
```

I have created an application where i refund shipping amount online when i upload a csv with order numbers.
but for some order it did not pass through as i get exception & the execution stops.

I need to skip if error thrown & start execution of another row in csv.

Comment: any thoughts how to fix it ?

Comment: Please provide some code, in what line exactly you have your problem, then I should be able to point you in right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just catch the exception where you want to continue execution...

```
try {
    SomeOperation();
} catch (SomeException $e) {
    // do nothing... php will ignore and continue    
}
```

Or you can add error message in log

```
try {
    /* Some logic that could throw an Exception */
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
}
```

It will continue your execution.

Comment: The code fails here - catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                        if (!$captureTxn) {
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline credit memo.'),
                                $e
                            );
                        }
                        throw $e;
                    }

Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php

Comment: After this exception the rest of the execution does not ru

Comment: Yes , that's why i have said that not to write anything in catch

Comment: try {
        /* Some logic that could throw an Exception */
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
    }

Comment: no i can not update like this